# Organization chart using HTML, CSS and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I introduced an organization chart that I found here:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/eN3Q8

Everything worked fine but my tree got bigger horizontally and it breaks like this:
[image]

I would like to add a scroll bar using overflow-x property but it doesn't work:

```css
.tree ul {
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Here is a CodePen link: https://codepen.io/vladnicu/pen/zYqwdyv

Thanks!

Comment: You want this to be aligned properly, right?

Comment: @NikhilSingh, yes, and it is. only when the tree is to large on horizontally it breaks instead of adding a scrollbar

Comment: Yeah I saw that code on codepen it was working fine, so the issue is only on bigger viewport right?

Comment: If you want to make it look small so that it does work on small viewports too, then you can use `transform: scale(0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a `min-width` to avoid that your chart to break like this:

```
.tree {
  min-width: 676px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

In your example, `676px` in the last width for which it works properly. That's why I have chosen it.

Now you are able to scroll horizontally as desired:

[image: Resulting scrollable containers]

Comment: You are the hero!